# Matching controls with time-dependent covariates to treated cases with varying treatment time without replacement

Tags: r, match, propensity-score-matching, matchit

I want to estimate the effect of treatment X on variable Y by matching for covariates balance on treatment and control groups using R and the [`MatchIt`](https://kosukeimai.github.io/MatchIt/index.html) package.

I'm compiling a retrospective cohort, and the treatment-time varies across the treatment cases. Moreover, I have multiple covariates (COV_A, COV_B...) that depend on the treatment time. I use a large database to mine controls and query the dependent covariates for a given treatment time. This is a large sample with thousand of treated cases, tens of thousands of potential controls, and many covariates.

To achieve this, I used SQL query to manually perform an "exact match" on some of the covariates as a kind of "initial matching" (for example, checking which controls have been monitored long enough to be treated in a given time). This initial step resulted in a table with multiple rows of potential control cases to match each treated case (TREAD_ID). For each row/case of potential control, I mined the time-depended covariates respecting the treated case treatment time.

The result is a table of potential controls that are stratified for each treatment case. **This means that a control case can appear more than once with a different or the same treatment time, and the covariates change accordingly.**

My intention is to use the `matchit` function to perform some kind of *distance matching* inside a *stratum matching* using `method = "nearest"` and `exact="TREAT_ID"` for example.

### Simplified Example Table

| CONTROL_ID | TREAT_ID | TREATMENT_TIME | COV_A | COV_B |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| C-1 | T-1 | 1.5 | 0.6 | 185 |
| C-2 | T-1 | 1.5 | 0.7 | 123 |
| C-3 | T-1 | 1.5 | 0.8 | 182 |
| C-4 | T-1 | 1.5 | 0.6 | 185 |
| C-1 | T-2 | 2.2 | 0.9 | 160 |
| C-2 | T-2 | 2.2 | 1.4 | 150 |
| C5 | T-2 | 2.2 | 0.9 | 48 |
| C-6 | T-2 | 2.2 | 3.3 | 113 |

* *Notice that controls C-1 and C-2 appears twice...*

### The Question:

I want to do matching "without replacement" (each control unit is matched to only one treated unit) - **How can I achieve this if the initial table contains duplicates of the same control cases (some of which with different values for covariates)?**

I also want to be able to:

- have control over the order of matching, and begin with the smallest stratum and move ahead...
- be able to achieve this also with 1:k matching ratio

*(Maybe my whole attitude to the problem is wrong, I'll also be happy to hear different solutions...)*

Comment: Have you looked into the `unit.id` argument?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TL;DR: I used @Noah's suggestion and the `unit.id` argument.

### Full solution

I united the treated cases into the stratified control cases from the example in the question and added the `MATCHING_STRATA` and `MATCHING_CASE` columns:

| ID | MATCHING_STRATA | MATCHIN_CASE | TREATMENT_TIME | COV_A | COV_B |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| T-1 | T-1 | TREATED | 1.5 | 1.2 | 112 |
| C-1 | T-1 | CONTROL | 1.5 | 0.6 | 185 |
| C-2 | T-1 | CONTROL | 1.5 | 0.7 | 123 |
| C-3 | T-1 | CONTROL | 1.5 | 0.8 | 182 |
| C-4 | T-1 | CONTROL | 1.5 | 0.6 | 185 |
| T-2 | T-2 | TREATED | 2.2 | 1.6 | 140 |
| C-1 | T-2 | CONTROL | 2.2 | 0.9 | 160 |
| C-2 | T-2 | CONTROL | 2.2 | 1.4 | 150 |
| C-5 | T-2 | CONTROL | 2.2 | 0.9 | 48 |
| C-6 | T-2 | CONTROL | 2.2 | 3.3 | 113 |

And then used the `matchit` function with `exact="MATCHING_STRATA"` to look into each stratum individually and `unit.id="ID"` to declare no replacement all across strata:

```
MatchIt::matchit(MATCHING_CASE ~ COV_A + COV_B, 
                 data = df, 
                 method = "nearest",
                 exact="MATCHING_STRATA",
                 unit.id="ID",
                 replace = FALSE)
```